# How to get the absolute height and width of the available display size in pixels

Tags: java, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am looking for absolute height and width of the available display in pixels like we do in android

```
activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

or

```
activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

Comment: I found the answer. For Height we can use `ability.getResourceManager().getDeviceCapability().height` and for width `ability.getResourceManager().getDeviceCapability().width`. It returns in virtual pixels (vps).

Answer (score 0):

You can still use this interface on Huawei phones.